# How to get the value type from an output iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++03

Let's say that I have a C container (e.g., `MyContainer`) with contained objects stored as `void*` pointers. The only way to iterate through the elements of this container is via two interface functions:

1. `getFirstElem(MyContainer const&, void*)`: Outputs the first element of the container.
2. `getNextElem(MyContainer const&, void*)`: Outputs the next element of the container.

I want to code a generic function that iterates through the elements of this C container via the interface functions mentioned above and copy their values into a C++ container (e.g. `std::vector`).

What I've done so far:

```
template<typename OutputIterator>
void
copy_container(MyContainer const &cont, OutputIterator first) {
  typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::value_type elem;
  if(getFirstElem(cont, &elem)) {
    do {
      *first = elem;
      ++first;
    } while(getNextElem(cont, &elem))    
  }
}
```

The above example works OK with normal iterators. However, it fails to compile with output iterators (e.g., `copy_container(cont, std::back_inserter(myvector));`).

The reason is that `std::iterator_traits::value_type` results in `void` in cases where the argument type is an output iterator.

**Is there a way to make this generic function work for output iterators as well?**

I know that in C++11 it could be done by using `decltype` (e.g., `decltype(*first)`), but I'm particularly interested in pre-C++11 solutions since I use an old C++ compiler (gcc v4.4.7).

Comment: Even in C++11, `decltype(*first)` is not the solution cause of *proxy* (as it is the case for `std::back_inserter`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As correctly observed, the `value_type` of an output iterator is `void`. So there not much to do apart from replacing this :

```
typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::value_type elem;
```

with this

```
decltype(*first) elem;
```

(even though the Standard doesn't guarantee it'll work - a proxy might be returned by dereferencing an output iterator).

As you said no C++11 solution so a redesign might be needed. Here are some options:

### 1. Pass the container

Instead of an iterator to the first element, you could pass a reference to the container. It seems like all you want is a `push_back`.

```
template<template<typename,typename> class stlContainer>
void copy_container(
    MyMontainer const &cont, OutputIterator first) 
{ 
    // insertion in stlContainer
```

then all you need is a layer of traits to dispatch to the right implementation of insertion per container

### 2. Pass an extra template parameter

The value type could be an extra template parameter.

```
template<typename value_type, typename OutputIterator>
void copy_container(MyMontainer const &cont, OutputIterator first) 
{
    value_type elem;
...
```

Comment: `decltype(*first)` is still the `std::back_inserter` for me (gcc 4.8.1). And it is `std::back_inserter::operator =(const value_type&)` which is implemented for proxy.

Comment: @Jarod42 What's the dispute here? In `back_insert_iterator` and `raw_storage_iterator`, operator * returns a proxy object for use in “dereferenced assignment,” typically a reference to the iterator itself. Am I communicating sth different?

Comment: It was just a clarification/example that `decltype(*first)` doesn't work for all cases.

Answer (score 5):

You may use typetraits and specialization

```
template <typename IT>
struct it_value_type
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type elem;
};

template <typename Container>
struct it_value_type<std::back_insert_iterator<Container>>
{
    typedef typename Container::value_type elem;
};

template <typename Container>
struct it_value_type<std::front_insert_iterator<Container>>
{
    typedef typename Container::value_type elem;
};
```

And then you code becomes:

```
template<typename OutputIterator>
void
copy_container(MyContainer const &cont, OutputIterator first) {
    typename it_value_type<OutputIterator>::elem elem;
    if (getFirstElem(cont, &elem)) {
        do {
            *first = elem;
            ++first;
        } while (getNextElem(cont, &elem));
    }
}
```

Comment: How this solution works? When you call `copy_container` with a `back_inserter` how the compiler will decide which `it_value_type` struct to use, since both `template <typename IT> struct it_value_type` and `template <typename Container>
struct it_value_type<std::back_insert_iterator<Container>>` are possible.

Comment: @Dejan: `std::back_inserter` is more specialized than `IT`.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to solve this, I did it like this:

```
template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<typename T::container_type::value_type, void>, size_t> read(T first, size_t count)
{
    typedef typename T::container_type::value_type value_type;
```

I have another one for the usual iterator.