# How to obtain "assignable type" for an arbitrary (STL) output iterator in C++

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

The C++ Standard requires that the typedef `value_type` in `std::iterator_traits<OutputIterator>` is set to `void` for an output iterator of type `OutputIterator`. Nevertheless, it is perfectly reasonable (and absolutely required in my code) to deduce - for a given output iterator type `OutputIterator` -, what will be the admissible type (without referring to any implicit conversion) `o` in an expression of the form

```
*it = o
```

where `it` is an object of type `OutputIterator`.

Ideally, I'd like to use TMP to define a template class `my_iterator_traits` which defines a typedef `assignable_type`, so that `my_iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::assignable_type` would equal `decltype( o )`. Any suggestions how to achieve this?

I even do not know how to achieve this if I enumerate all possible STL iterator types by defining template specializations. For example, the following code won't compile, as the compiler cannot deduce the template parameter `T`:

```
template <typename Iterator> struct my_iterator_traits;

//[...]

//Does NOT compile, compiler cannot deduce type T
template <typename T> struct my_iterator_traits<std::vector<T>::iterator>
{
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::value_type assignable_type;
    //Another option, but I think not so clean:
    //typedef T assignable_type;
};
```

---

EDIT: This is a sketch (without context) for a case where I run into the problem. Suggest that you want to edit elements of a container on the binary level. The object `first` is an (input) iterator, which allows me to access input elements of a known size (of 2 bytes in this case). I want to write them to a "binary output" via an output iterator `result` which accepts single byte (output) objects. I.e., I do not want to specify what the "single byte type" of the output iterator should be. (Quasi-)Code:

```
const typename my_iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::assignable_type* ptr;

for( size_type i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++first )
{
    ptr = reinterpret_cast<const typename my_iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::assignable_type*>( &( *first ) );
    *result = ptr[0]; ++result;
    *result = ptr[1]; ++result;
}
```

I fear that without the `reinterpret_cast` it might happen that there exist cases where some implicit conversion alters the binary structure. I just want to copy the bits to the target, no matter what the target is and how it can be accessed via the abstract interface that is provided by the output iterator. The only requirement is that the target can be accessed byte by byte via the output iterator.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25118328

Comment: @DrewDormann: If I understand it correctly, the suggested solutions only work if you pass the container type as additional information. I don't want to break the interface in this brutal way: Just deduce from the output iterator what can be assigned to it.

Comment: `std::vector<T>::iterator` could be `T*`.  The mapping (from `T` to `std::vector<T>::iterator`) need not be injective, and it can involve nearly arbitrary compile time computation (which even if injective, is infeasible to reverse in the general case).  Can you explain what it is you are trying to do, *as well as* the technical issue you ran into along the way?

Comment: Why not change your binary output iterator to accept anything standard layout, and write out the bytes, if it is supposed to be a binary output stream?  Why are you using multiple different output iterators that take different "sizes" and "types" of value?  Second, input iterators need not persist -- `*it` just returns something convertible to `value_type`, it need not be a `value_type const&` or whatever.  Third, you have absolutely no guards against UB there (reinterpreting something like that is dangerous).

Comment: @Yakk: I have no control over OutputIterator, it is just supposed to be an abstract (single byte) interface provided by the user. The above code does not assume more than that the assignment "*it = o" is possible, not that *it is value_type const& or sth. (imagine a back insertion iterator). Finally: Assume that you could check (that's the topic here :p...) that the OutputIterator is a single byte type, and if the proper type of o in *it = o can be deduced, how can there be undefined behavior in the code fragment? The operations *result = ptr[i] are of the specified form.

Comment: @sperber depending on the single byte type, trap representations are legal.  A custom single byte type would make it easy.  It is only legal to do that kind of byte scanning to ... 1 or 2?  types.

Comment: @Yakk I guess std::uint8_t is safe if it is available?! As far as I know, std::uint8_t is part of the C++ standard by now BUT is not required to be available on a given platform...

Comment: @sperber I do not recall.  Ask a question here on SO and someone might recall, or standard delve.  I remember some discussion about it.  My guess would be something like `char` and `unsigned char`, but that would only be a guess.  `uint8_t` may not qualify?  Uncertain.  Rather than converting to the arbitrary single-byte type, convert to a known safe single-byte type.  I guess narrowing conversion possibility remains?  Or overflow undefinedness?  But that is a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your question cannot be answered in general.

As an example, here is an output iterator that, while it technically only takes one type to `operator=`, actually takes any type:

```
template<class OS>
struct ostream_proxy {
  void* v;
  void(*f)(void*, OS&);
  template<class O>
  friend O& operator<<(O& o, ostream_proxy p) {
    p.f(p.v, o);
    return o;
  }
  template<class X, class pX = typename std::decay_t<X>::type*>
  ostream_proxy( X&& x ):
    v(&x),
    f(
      [](void* px, OS& os) {
        os << &static_cast<pX>(px);
      }
    )
  {}
};
template<class OS>
std::ostream_iterator<ostream_proxy<OS>> it_out(OS& os) {
  return {os};
}
template<class OS, class CharT>
std::ostream_iterator<ostream_proxy<OS>> it_out(OS& os, const CharT* delim) {
  return {os, delim};
}
```

now above I was lazy, and I used `std::ostream_iterator` with a proxy type.  However, it is legal for `operator=` on an output iterator to be overloaded, or be a `template` operator.  And if that is the case, then there is no "one type without conversion" that the output iterator accepts.

(A less lazy/hacky version would reimplement `ostream_iterator<>` to have a `template operator=`, and just write *any* type out.  In my opinion, this would be a good implementation of `std::ostream_iterator<void>`, like `std::less<void>` (aka `std::less<>`)).

It is easy to check if there is a way to assign a given type to the iterator, but determining what type involves "no conversions" is not possible in the general case.  In specific cases, there are a myriad of hacks.

Like most "given a function object, give me its signature" this question assumes that there *is* a fixed type, or there *should be* a fixed type, involved.  Output iterators have valid expressions that can be used to load them, not specific types.

Comment: Thank you for your great example. It is clear to me that the question can not be answered for any type in a meaningful way. What I merely want is a "traits class" that gives me - via template specializations - an answer for cases where it makes sense to ask what the type "o" should be. If someone could suggest a solution for the "std::vector<T>" case cited above, where the answer clearly (?) should be "T", that would be sufficient to replicate code for all cases of interest.